# howTo set set default tab in copyQ in commandline?

Tags: command-line, copyq

i using in ubuntu

copyq as clipboard manager

https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

and use little scripts for the tab management like.

it should add clipboard contents to the the new tab.

or in other words: the default tab should changed, not "clipboard" anymore. usually "clipboard" is the default tab, and all clipboard is collected there.

any idea?

i search a console command for set a tab as default like:

```bash
copyq myNewTabNameAsDefaultTabForCollectContent
```

but it gives me no error but defautl tab is still "clipboard"

is you want see the complete script (autokey-script that runs command-line commands) here it is:

```py
import subprocess
previous_class = None
while True:
    # Get the active window's class name
    active_class = window.get_active_class()

    # Check if the active class has changed
    if active_class != previous_class:
        # Create a new tab in CopyQ with the same name as the active class with a empty value
        create_tab_command = ["copyq", "tab", active_class, "add", '']
        subprocess.run(create_tab_command)

        # Enable the CopyQ tab with the same name
        enable_tab_command = ["copyq", active_class]
        subprocess.run(enable_tab_command)

        # Set the newly created tab as the default tab
        set_default_tab_command = ["copyq", "config", "default_tab", active_class]
        subprocess.run(set_default_tab_command)

        # Update the previous class variable
        previous_class = active_class

    # Add a small delay before checking again
    time.sleep(1)
```